# Make a function parameter be of a protocol type that also conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-protocols

I want to make a function that takes a parameter of a protocol type and ensure that that protocol type also conforms to another protocol type. Is there a way I can do this? Or do I have to fundamentally rethink my approach here?

Example:

```
// This doesn't extend CaseIterable itself because I would like to use it as a concrete type and not just a generic constraint
protocol MyProtocol {
    /*some protocol stuff*/
}

enum myEnum: MyProtocol, CaseIterable {
    /*some enum stuff*/
}

func<T: CaseIterable>(_ myEnum: MyProtocol.Type) 
where MyProtocol.Type: CaseIterable {
    myEnum.allCases //   <--- This is what I would like to do
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your function signature to use the generic type constraint as the input argument's type and restrict the generic type parameter to be `MyProtocol` and `CaseIterable`.

```
func enumFunc<T: MyProtocol & CaseIterable>(_ myEnum: T.Type) {
    myEnum.allCases //   <--- This is what I would like to do
}
```

Comment: why not simply `func enumFunc<T: CaseIterable & MyProtocol>(_ myEnum: T.Type)  {`?

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, that's even simpler, updated my answer